# Correlation between two variables produces NA

Tags: r, correlation, na

I am calculating the correlarion between each variable with the target feature, in a dataframe. It works great aside from one variable, `Age`, which is not producing the correlation, instead I get an NA. I removed all NA values before even starting the analysis. So the data is clean.

This is the code: (`PD` is the target variable and I want to compare it with all other variables. `PD` is binary)

```
pearsons = c()
for (i in 1:length(colnames(Train_set))){
  pearsons[i] = cor(Train_set[,i], Train_set$PD, method = 'pearson')
}
```

This is the data structre: (only some of it)

```
> glimpse(Train_set)
Rows: 1,219
Columns: 56
$ PD                            <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,…
$ gender                        <int> 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,…
$ cancer_type                   <int> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,…
$ Treatment                     <int> 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5,…
$ totaldata_new.Age             <int> 50, 66, 51, 60, 31, 70, 51, 56, 65, 62, 55, 69, 32, 82, 60, 49, 56, 59, 50, 51, 70, 74…
$ Adipocytes                    <dbl> 0.000000000, 0.000000000, 0.005592077, 0.005844092, 0.038175712, 0.000000000, 0.005063…
$ B.cells                       <dbl> 0.045214394, 1.300478781, 0.184967801, 0.032890485, 0.041641426, 0.006477740, 0.653999…
$ Basophils                     <dbl> 0.120695085, 0.065615816, 0.362173522, 0.039214941, 0.225555640, 0.056926623, 0.019076…
```

`totaldata_new.Age` is the Age variable. I tried setting it `as.numeric()` and `as.integer()` but both didn't work.

This is the training set,

```
structure(list(PD = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), gender = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), cancer_type = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Treatment = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L), totaldata_new.Age = c(50L, 66L, 51L, 
60L, 31L, 70L, 51L, 56L, 65L, 62L), Adipocytes = c(0, 0, 0.00559207695850587, 
0.00584409167696122, 0.0381757121622292, 0, 0.00506330308366599, 
0, 0.0156430635414994, 0), B.cells = c(0.0452143935493372, 1.30047878079526, 
0.184967800962064, 0.0328904854435036, 0.0416414264467815, 0.00647774047514386, 
0.653999365837062, 0.0331653878504112, 0.0286461940371656, 0.0888471904628742
), Basophils = c(0.120695085116671, 0.0656158162440011, 0.362173521572841, 
0.0392149412975555, 0.225555640419744, 0.0569266227666268, 0.0190762558461507, 
0.0733199539844435, 0.20291673586147, 0.0757313145147394), CD4..memory.T.cells = c(0, 
0.24081994997988, 0, 0.0084070550945875, 0, 0, 0.0704387567897827, 
0, 0.0177784010286187, 0.00653794301542519), CD4..naive.T.cells = c(0, 
0.222121262122827, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0337776019379054, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("Pt10", 
"Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt26", "Pt27", 
"Pt28"), class = "data.frame")
```

Why is this variable producing NA, while other variables give good results of the correlation?

Comment: Calling your sample data `df`, `cor(df$totaldata_new.Age, df$PD)` gives
`0.0344184`. If you're seeing `NA` on your full data, you should check your assumption that you've removed all the `NA`s. What does `anyNA(Train_set$totaldata_new.Age)` tell you? Perhaps new NAs were introduced. Otherwise, I think we'll need to encourage you to find a subset that illustrates the problem, as this sample seems to work fine.

Comment: The other reason to get `NA` values is if there is variance. Running your loop on the sample data, we get a warning on the `Cancer_type` variable and an `NA` result because there is only a single value. But we can see from the sample that `totaldata_new.Age` does have non-zero variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are NA values in the columns of interest.
To avoid this problem, there is the parameter 'use' in the 'cor'-function, which the help explains as:

> "giving a method for computing covariances in the presence of missing
> values."

I'd recommend changing your code to:

```
pearsons[i] = cor(Train_set[,i], Train_set$PD, method = 'pearson',
                  use = "complete.obs")
```

Hope that helps!
Samuel